# How to put my PHP results into an output variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, random

The code below selects rows from the database table but I want to select 10 random rows and put them in an output variable like the code below.Not csv in particular but to imitate the one below.

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM customer");
$numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($numberOfRows > 0) {
    $values = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM customer");
    while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_row($values)) {
     for ($j=0;$j<$numberOfRows;$j++) {
      $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
     }
     $csv_output .= "\n";
    }

    }

print $csv_output;
exit;
```

First i want to select ten random rows then output them in something like the code above.

My code:

```
<?php 

DEFINE ('DBUSER', ''); 
DEFINE ('DBPW', ''); 
DEFINE ('DBHOST', ''); 
DEFINE ('DBNAME', ''); 

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    exit();
}

$dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
if (!$dbs) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    exit(); 
}

 $query = 'Select * FROM Funsies
 Order By Rand()
 Limit 5'; 

 $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
 ?>
```

Comment: find a basic tutorial on php\MySQL

Comment: Do you recommend anything more advance than w3schools sql?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
  FROM random AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT (RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM random)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1
INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\users\\desktop\\file_name.csv' 
fields TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: How do i put the ten rows it retrieved into a $csv_output like the top code?